# Asp.net MVC 4 Jquery validator not hitting InvalidHandler

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, customvalidator

I'm struggling on this problem... 
I've override my master page to change invalid hightlight and Unhightlight classes and to modify the InvalidHandler like below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $.validator.setDefaults({
        ignore: [],
        invalidHandler: function (event, validator) {
            $(".tab-content").find("div.tab-pane:hidden:has(div.has-error)").each(function (index, tab) {
                var id = $(tab).attr("id");
                alert(id);
                $('a[href="#' + id + '"]').tab('show');
            });
        },
        highlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
            if (element.type === 'radio') {
                this.findByName(element.name).addClass("bad").removeClass("good");
            } else {
                $(element).addClass("bad").removeClass("good");
                $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('good').addClass('bad');
            }
        },
        unhighlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
            if (element.type === 'radio') {
                this.findByName(element.name).removeClass("bad").addClass("good");
            } else {
                $(element).removeClass("bad").addClass(validClass);
                $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('bad').addClass('good');
            }
        }
    });
```

The Hightlight and Unhightlight has been hited, but  InvalidHandler doesn't...
Could somebody help me?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

If you're using jQuery Unobtrusive Validation, it doesn't necessarily respect the default, and I haven't been able to get invalidHandler working either.

You can subscribe to an event that is thrown:

```
`$('form').on('invalid-form', function (...) { });`
```

Or I've also found in the [jQuery unobtrusive source](https://github.com/aspnet/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/blob/0f4aac9519eb471dc509804dde12718ee8fa7652/src/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js#L128) that they try pull options out of `jQuery.validator.unobstrusive.options` so you can do this:

```
jQuery.validator.unobtrusive.options = 
jQuery.validator.unobtrusive.options || {};
jQuery.validator.unobtrusive.options.invalidHandler = function (...) { };
```

Either way, for me I'm getting it called twice, which is painful too.